# Добраться до текущего ребенка в текущем родителе

Tags: javascript

Ребят, из головы вылетело и не знаю как по другому. Вернее знаю, но решение психически - больное!

Вообщем есть такой код:

```
elements.forEach((element, i) => {
        const input = document.querySelector('.create-title'); 

        console.log(input);
    })
})
```

elements > карточки
element > текущая карточка
Как в текущей карточке добраться до create-title

Я помню только вариант, когда нужно подниматься до родителя, прогонять  for, где  i  по длине элементов, искать проверкой через контейнс нужный класс. Такое решение считаю не лаконичным!

Comment: как ни странно, но `querySelector` есть не только у `document`.

Comment: У вас 23к репутации, однако, как не странно, вы не ответили на вопрос, а только запутали.

Comment: я же не ответ вам написал, а мыслительный процесс запустил комментарием, что называется "наводящий вопрос" обычно. Я тут своей целью не ставлю выдавать людям готовые ответы, да и мало кто ставит. опыт он достигается не копирование готового, а когда сам задачу решаешь,  и тут в решениях и подсказывают,а не решают за вас

Comment: Да, спасибо!  Ну про то, что querySelector применяется не только у document, узнал реально впервые. Учитывая, что я давно знаю  js. А там оказывается ниже ссылки были с примерами на MDN. И как я жил без нее.

Comment: Можно и так, но есть еще  children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам поможет `querySelectorAll()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

это если объектов с классом `.create-title` у вас много

функция выдаст список объектов и работайте с ними как хотите

опять же к любому объекту вы также можете применить данную функцию или `querySelector` и будет осуществлён поиск уже только внутри объекта, например:

```
obj = document.querySelector('.xxx')
elem = obj.querySelector('yyy')
```

**P.S.**

приведённый вами код можно переписать так:

```
let objects = document.querySelectorAll('.create-title');

objects.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```